# ObservableCollection não faz o binding

Tags: c#, wpf

**Estou com a seguinte situação:**

Faço a instância de uma propriedade observável no construtor:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> _os { get; private set; }

    public EditorServicosViewModel()
    {
        OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();
    }
```

Quando adiciono um item à coleção dentro de  um método:

```
    public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
    {
        OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OSItem);
        OnPropertyChanged("OS");
    }
```

Ele não faz a ligação com o `TextBlock`.
Mas se faço a instância dentro do `método`:

```
    public void OnTabClicked(ListaServicosTab listaServicosTab)
    {
        OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();
        OS.Add(listaServicosTab.vm.OS);
        OnPropertyChanged("OS");
    }
```

Ele faz o binding.

Alguém pode me dizer o motivo disso, pois já fiz inúmeros malabarismos e não consigo resolver, pois não quero a instância dentro do método e sim no construtor.

Comment: Reveja a declaração da propriedade há algo de errado nisto `public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> _os; { get; private set; }`

Comment: Não será `public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> OS { get; private set; }`?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente o problema é o encapsulamento da propriedade _os:

`public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> _os { get; private set; }`

Como o método `set` é privado, o binding que é realizado pela biblioteca System.Data não tem acesso a ele, tente retirar o encapsulamento do método set, conforme abaixo:

`public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> _os { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

O ObservableCollection é uma classe que faz "binding" com a propriedade itemSource. Então apenas os elementos que possuem a tal propriedade fazem o "*listens*" da coleção.

Você está fazendo binding com um textblock que não contém a propriedade itemSource porém se você quiser continuar com o textblock você tem que utilizar criar uma classe de converter que implementa a interface `IValueConverter`. Mas eu recomendo que você utilize um `ItemsControl` dentro da textblock e definindo o `ItemTemplate` com um textblock.

**.cs:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel> OS { get; private set; }

public EditorServicosViewModel()
{
    OS = new ObservableCollection<Model.OSModel>();
    itemscontrol.ItemsSource = OS;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Width="654">
                     <ItemsControl x:Name="itemscontrol">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</TextBlock>
```

Ou utilizar um controle de lista com o `listview` ou `listbox`